# Is the word 'result' as a singular noun grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, articles, irregular-plurals

Take ownership of your tasks, see them to completion, and then take pride in the result.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. Part of the culture here is to have questions show the work you’ve done yourself so far. This helps the community to address more precisely the parts that actually puzzle you. When you think about the question more deeply yourself, it also tends to make for a more interesting question. Please [edit] your question to include information about why you think the word _result_ seems odd to you in that context.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but "result" and "results" have different meanings:

"... and then take pride in the result." = and then take pride in the overall result of seeing all the tasks to completion, i.e. the final, total result: a result = one result.

"... and then take pride in the results." = and then take pride in the individual results of each of the tasks seen to completion, i.e. each of the results. Results = more than one result.